# django search by one field and update or create on another field(s)

Tags: python, django

For example:

test_table

```
Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'username', 'varchar(64)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'status', 'tinyint(1)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
```

I want to search by username='john', if it's exist, then update status to 1;

Django has update_or_create function but it works when both username and status exist;

e.g.
data already in table:

`username:john
status:0`

I want to change status to 1

If I use update_or_create(), since there is no row like "username:john, status:1", so it will "create", not "update" status to 1:

`TestTable.objects.update_or_create(username="John",status=1)`

Of course you can always : search first, then "if...create; else...update". But I wonder if there is some django functions I can use or something I didn't notice when using update_or_create().

Thanks!

Comment: `TestTable.objects.filter(username="John").update(status=1)`

Comment: No. If that data line doesn't exist, filter+update won't generate(or insert) a new line. That's why I need "create" some times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try:
    o = TestTable.objects.get(username='John')
    o.status = 1
    o.save(update_fields=["status"])
except TestTable.DoesNotExist:
    o = TestTable(username='John', status=1)
```

Comment: It's easy using try-except DoesNotExist or ```
o = TestTable.object.filter(username='John')

if o:
    o.status = 1
    o.save()
else:
    TestTable.object.create(username='John', status=1)``` But it takes too much code. I wonder if something exist like update_or_create which can close my question with 1 line. ^_^